# How do you simplify $e^{{147i}\left(\frac{1-\left(\frac{1}{e^{8i}}\right)^{10}}{1-\frac{1}{e^{8i}}}\right)}$ in terms of cis?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How do you simplify $$e^{{147i}\left(\frac{1-\left(\frac{1}{e^{8i}}\right)^{10}}{1-\frac{1}{e^{8i}}}\right)}$$ in terms of cis?

I was trying to solve a question that was a geometric series and am now stuck on how to simplify this. Any help?

Comment: What is "cis" ?

Comment: $\cos\theta+i*\sin\theta$

Comment: Pretty sure $\cos(n)+i\sin(n)=e^n$, so I'm basically asking for what the exponent of $e$ is. But I'm not sure what form the answer is.

Comment: Not quite. Given $n\in\mathbb{R}$, then $\cos(n)+i\sin(n)=e^{i\cdot n}\neq e^{n}$. If you can simplify the exponent, using cis is easy if you want it in that form

Comment: oops srry that's what I meant